# React Quill Determine is the Current Line in focus is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, react-quill

Using Library react-quill
unable to determine is the current line is empty

```
import './App.css';
import ReactQuill, { Quill } from "react-quill";
import { toolbarOptions } from './toolbar_options'
import "react-quill/dist/quill.bubble.css";


function App() {

  

  const handleQuillChange = (content, delta, source, editor) => {
    
  }


  const handleChangeSelection = (range, source, editor) => {
  
    }
  


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactQuill
        theme="bubble"
        placeholder="Compose an epic..."
        modules={{ toolbar: toolbarOptions }}
        onChange={handleQuillChange}
        onChangeSelection={handleChangeSelection}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is there any method that im missing that tells if the current focussed line is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution
ref needs to be passed to ReactQuill

```
  const handleChangeSelection = (range, source, editor) => {
    if (range == null || range == undefined) return;
    if (range.length === 0) {
      let [block, offset] = quillRef.current.editor.scroll.descendant(Block, range.index);

      if (block != null && block.domNode.firstChild instanceof HTMLBRElement) {
        
///Toggle the desired usage
        toggleController(true)

      } else {
      ///Toggle the desired usage
        toggleController(false)
      }
    } else {
     ///Toggle the desired usage
      toggleController(false)
    }
  }


.......


 <ReactQuill
        className='editor'
        ref={quillRef}
        theme="bubble"
        placeholder="Compose an epic..."
        modules={{ toolbar: toolbarOptions }}
        onChangeSelection={handleChangeSelection}
      />
```